# Unhandled Exception,passing object?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic

```
class Fraction {
public:
    Fraction();
    Fraction(int);
    Fraction(int, int);
    ~Fraction();
    void setNum(int);
    void setDenom(int);
    int getNum(void) const;
    int getDenom(void) const;
    void print(void);
private:
    int num;
int denom;
};

class Circle {
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(Fraction& arg1);
   ~Circle();
    void print(void);
protected:
    Fraction *radius;
};
```

and

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction() {
    num = 0;
    denom = 1;
}
Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d) {
    num = n;
    denom = d;
}
Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& arg) {
    num = arg.num;
    denom = arg.denom; 
    return *this;
}
Fraction::~Fraction() {
}

//Circle

Circle::Circle() {
    radius->setNum(1);
    radius->setDenom(1);
}
Circle::Circle(Fraction& arg1) {
    radius->setNum(arg1.getNum());
    radius->setDenom(arg1.getDenom());
}
Circle::~Circle() {
     delete this->radius;
}
```

The problem comes when i create the objects in main()

```
 Fraction* fPtr = new Fraction(4, 1);
 Circle* cPtrA = new Circle(*fPtr);
```

Both of these are classes.
First i use the copy constructor to set Numerator of classFraction to 4 and Denominator to 1.

Then i want to pass that (4, 1) into my classCircle but i get this error of unhandled exception through debugger

Comment: Why is `radius` a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following constructor, you haven't assigned anything to `radius`

```
Circle::Circle(Fraction& arg1) {
    radius->setNum(arg1.getNum());
    radius->setDenom(arg1.getDenom());
}
```

There's different options, but if you want to have a copy of the `Fraction` in the `Circle`, you could do this:

```
Circle::Circle(Fraction& arg1) : radius(new Fraction(arg1)) {
}
```

Probably it would be better to just store a copy of the object instead

```
class Circle {
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(const Fraction& arg1);
   ~Circle();
    void print(void);
protected:
    Fraction radius;
};

Circle::Circle(const Fraction& arg1) : radius(arg1)) {
}
```

Note that by making the argument a `const` reference you indicate to the compiler and other users that the passed `Fraction` won't be changed by the call.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize `radius` in both your copy constructor and in your default constructor. This causes the exception when you try to call `setNum` or `setDenom`. You can fix this by either allocating a `Fraction` for `radius` like below.

```
Circle::Circle() : radius(new Fraction())
{
    radius->setNum(1);
    radius->setDenom(1);
}

Circle::Circle(const Fraction &other) : radius(new Fraction())
{
    radius->setNum(arg1.getNum());
    radius->setDenom(arg1.getDenom());
}
```

Idiomatically it's generally preferred to initialize `radius` through copy construction as well.

```
Circle::Circle(const Fraction &other) : radius(new Fraction(other))
{
}
```

Remember to delete the object in your destructor.

```
Circle::~Circle()
{
    delete radius;
}
```

You can eliminate the allocation by storing `radius` by value instead of by pointer.